# How can I practice pronouncing "Coke" so it is not mistaken for another word?

Tags: pronunciation, diphthongs

I always fear my conversation sounds like this:

> — What would you like to drink, sir?
>   — I will take some cock, thanks.
>   — *ROFL*.

Any tips on how to pronounce *Coke* so it is not mistaken for anything? :)

Comment: to make it simple: kok = cock, kouk = coke

Comment: ask for pepsi then?

Comment: serg, you just need to remember that the letter *o* has a different sound in each of those words.

Comment: "Coke" is short for "Coca Cola", with "Coca" being a reference to the same coca leaves that yield cocaine.  See if simply pronouncing the first syllable of "cocaine" seems to work for you.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/599686/2085).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Coke* is pronounced /kəʊk/ in British English and /koʊk/ in American English. *Cock* is pronounced /kɒk/ in British English and /kɑk/ in American English.

As you can see, it is the vowel sounds that are different. The two sounds are distinguished in two ways: (1) by one being a diphthong and the other being a monophthong, (the vowel sound changes quality in a diphthong and remains stable in a monophthong), and (2) the position of the tongue is different. The “long O” sound of *Coke* is a diphthong, whereas the “short O” sound of *cock* is a monophthong, and it is pronounced with the tongue in a lower position. Here is a vowel diagram for British English:
[image: British English vowel diagram]

As you can see the vowel sound of *Coke* starts with the tongue in the position for /ə/, which is in a middle neutral position, and it moves up and slightly back to the position for /ʊ/. The vowel sound of *cock*, on the other hand, is pronounced with the tongue very low and very far back in the mouth, and it doesn’t move during the production of the sound. The differences in American English are similar.

[Here](http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/wordscape/wordlist/socksoak.html) is a page discussing all the pairs of words in English that differ only by these sounds, which suggests that this sound pair is a frequent difficulty for non-native speakers of English. I would suggest looking up those word pairs in an online dictionary, like [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/) and listening carefully to the recordings for each pair of words to hear the differences between them.

Comment: What's the difference between half-closed and half-opened? Just how optimistic you are? :p

Comment: Tongue position is part of this but lip position is also part of it. Very difficult to teach this by writing and pictures.

Comment: @Shinto, true, but in English lip position and backness are linked—back vowels have rounded lips and front vowels do not.

Comment: @serg555, according to the Wikipedia article about [Ukrainian phonology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_phonology), the O sound of Ukrainian is ɔ, which is kind of in between the sounds for *Coke* and *cock*, so your confusion is understandable.

Comment: I have downvoted this answer as I think it goes into unnecessary detail.

Comment: @serg555: the problem is that Russian and Ukrainian don't really have diphtongs. So, to explain it in the most simple terms, "cock" is closer to "кок", while coke is closer to "ко́ук", where the "оу" is kind of one connected sound, rather than two separate ones. If you are familiar with musical terms, I would say that "cock" is *(mezzo) staccato*, while "coke" is *legato*.

Comment: Down voted for detail? Even when it includes a short two sentence summary at the start?

Answer (score 10):

It rhymes with "poke" and "joke", not "pock" and "jock". It's a long *o* sound.

Or you could just switch to Pepsi.

Comment: To expand on this, see [Kosmonaut's answer to a similar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2836/how-to-pronounce-beach-and-bitch-whats-the-difference/2849#2849).

Comment: Thanks, @RegDwight. Somehow I didn't remember seeing that answer before.

Comment: +1 for the Pepsi suggestion. Frankly if you have any trouble at all with this word sounding like the word for male genitalia in conversation, I'd avoid it like the plague until you are confident you have no trouble with it.

Answer (score 2):

> What would you like to drink, sir?
>   — I will take some cock, thanks.

Maybe it's the "take" as well. "I'd like a coke" or something.

Sorry but it's very difficult to teach pronunciation via typing words into a computer so it's hard to make a suggestion, except if you exaggerate the vowel enough "coke" will not sound anything like "cock" to a native speaker.

http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/wordscape/wordlist/socksoak.html

is a list of minimal pairs for this vowel pair.

Answer (score 1):

I can see how this can be a problem...

The difference between cock and coke is this (at least the best I can do in writing):

the "o" in c**o**ck is an "open" O. (your lips are pretty opened when you pronounce it : "r**o**ck", "s**o**ccer", "c**o**ffee"...)

the "o" in c**o**ke is more complicated. It's the combination of two sounds : a "closed" o (lips almost closed, not used a lot by itself in the english language) immediately followed by a "u" sound ("t**o** d**o**", "p**ooh**", "L**ou**isiana"...)

For future reference, the sound of the "o" in "c**o**ke" is the same as these : "r**o**se", c**o**de, cr**o**w, gr**o**w, rainb**o**w, cl**o**se, wind**o**w...

EDIT : You shouldn't say "I'll take a coke", you should say "I'll have a coke". Take isn't used properly and it adds misunderstanding to the mispronunciation.

Comment: Tonik, that's a good point about using *have* instead of *take*. It sounds more natural.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is giving detailed, technical answers. How about I give you a mental substitution for the word instead?
Think of the spelling as Coak or Coh-k instead. Make sure it's a long "o" pronounced like "oh". That should fix the issue once you practice using it. It took me a long time to stop pronouncing Aqua (ah-coo-wah) as Akwa (ak-wah), so I sort of understand your issue.